# DirectX.Capture FrameRates

Tags: directx, capture, frame-rate

I'm using DirectX.Capture library to save to an AVI fomr Webcam. I need video to be saved to have 50fps or more, but when i use this:

```
 capture.FrameRate = 59.994;
```

FrameRate doesn't change at all. It had 30 before that line and passing that line it keeps its 30. I tried other values, even 20 and 10, and nothing changes.

What else should i do so i can be able to change that value? or it is something regarding my hardware and i can hope it works in other machine?

Please help me, i don't know what to do.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

The source material (video, app/etc), is probably only being updated at 30fps, either because that is the way the video codec or app behaves, or because you have vsync turned on in the target app (check vsync settings, it might be getting forced by the video card drivers if there is hardware acceleration). The behaviour of DirectX.Capture is probably to clamp to the highest available framerate from the source.

If you *really* want to make the video 50fps, capture it at its native rate (30/29.97) and just resample the video using some other software (note that this would be a destructive operation since 50 is not a clean multiple of 30). This will be no different from what DX capture would do if you *could* force it at 50fps (even if its nonsensical due to the source material being at a lower framerate). FYI most video files are between 25 and 30 FPS.